# What am I doing wrong (data.table, R)?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm currently doing some tests with the `set` function in the `data.table` package in `R` and have the following code:

```
  dt= data.table(ans=rep(c(14,16),100))
  dt[,voy:=0.0]
  set(dt,which(dt[,ans]==14),"voy",log(dt[,ans]))
  dt
```

Note that I want to compute the logarithm of those cases having `ans=14` using the `set` function, but I'm not getting the correct result. This is the result I got:

```
  ans      voy
  1:  14 2.639057
  2:  16 0.000000
  3:  14 2.772589
  4:  16 0.000000
  5:  14 2.639057
  ---             
  196:  16 0.000000
  197:  14 2.639057
  198:  16 0.000000
  199:  14 2.772589
  200:  16 0.000000
```

You may note that for some rows the value of the variable `voy` is the expected `log(14)=2.639057` but for others cases having `ans=14` it is assigned `2.772589=log(16)`. So, I think I'm misusing the `set` function. How can I solve this?
I know the next code can be used to carry this out:

```
dt[ans==14,voy:=log(ans)]
```

But I want to translate this into the `set` function syntax.

Comment: Why? You demonstrate a feasible, good alternative. Why replace it with something more complicated?

Comment: You are right @Andrie, but I just want to make sure I understand the way the ``set`` function works. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to subset the data for the value parameter. In your case, the warning *Supplied 200 items to be assigned to 100 items of column 'voy' (100 unused)* could have given you an idea. You were picking one by one the first 100 values of `dt$ans`, which indeed are alternating 14's and 16's.

This way it works:

```
set(dt,which(dt[,ans]==14),"voy",log(dt[ans==14,ans]))
```

giving:

```
     ans      voy
  1:  14 2.639057
  2:  16 0.000000
  3:  14 2.639057
  4:  16 0.000000
  5:  14 2.639057
 ---             
196:  16 0.000000
197:  14 2.639057
198:  16 0.000000
199:  14 2.639057
200:  16 0.000000
```

But it's ugly code, as @Andrie already remarked.